# New to iOS development. Need Resources

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I just began iOS development, and find it relatively hard to comprehend. 
I have browsed through a lot of tutorials, and the Apple documentation too, but what i really need is tutorials that help- in understanding the basics before tackling actual problems. 
Any references anybody could point out would be highly appreciated. YouTube videos are also welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tack a look at video tutorial of [Lynda](http://www.lynda.com/). Its good to take a look at that video and than start developing app in iPhone.

For good tutorial my favorite sites are [Raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/), [EDUMobile](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/category/iphone-beginner-tutorials/), [mobileTutPlus](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/), [Technotopia](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Main_Page).

And for sample code i suggest [GITHub](https://github.com/), [Cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls), [Code4app](http://code4app.net/).

And this is really helpful books, [Programming in Objective-C 2.0 (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321566157), [Beginning iPhone Development: Exploring the iPhone SDK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430216263),

Answer (score 1):

Apple documentation is enough to know and learn. And also goto lynda.com and software-> Apple there you can find good Essential Training videos. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a book. Seriously. I like the ones from the Big Nerd Ranch.